# See through sprite?

Tags: unity, sprites, gimp

I used gimp to make a newspaper front page. When i import it into unity3D as a png and then rotate it you can see the print on the front reversed as if the newspaper was see-through. I had the same problem when I made a hanging sign for my dungeon. I you walked past the sign and looked back you could see the front of the sign reversed. Whats the trick to prevent this?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: This is called "backface culling" and is generally done by editing the shader inside Unity's own program folder.

Answer (score 1):

I would look into using a `plane` instead of a sprite for something like this and changing it's `texture` to be your image. Planes will not draw their backface. `Sprites` aren't really intended to be used in 3d in this way.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That didn't really work.because I want to rotate the newspaper and see a backface just like the hanging sign. if you walk past the sign and look back you won't see a sign at all. Not the desired result..

Comment: That's why you put a second copy of the plane or quad back-to-back with the first one.

Comment: There is no way to get the behavior you're looking for out-of-the-box I'm afraid... @DMGregory is correct the easiest way would be to have two planes back-to-back